# Always receive MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'. ERROR

Tags: java, ibm-mq, websphere-7

I am new to Web Sphere MQ.

I created a Queue Manager, Channel and Listener in AIX as follows:

```
crtmqm MY_Q_MGR

strmqm MY_Q_MGR

runmqsc

DEFINE LISTENER(MY_QM_LISTENER) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(5030)

DEFINE CHANNEL(MY_QM_CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(SDR) CONNAME('10.128.1.51(5030)') XMITQ('MY_Q_MGR') DISCINT(0)
```

Then I checked that QMGR is running. I saw listener in proc.

Then, I tried to create MQQueueManager from java as follows and I got `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.`

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;

public class MQSample {

  // code identifier
  static final String sccsid = "@(#) samples/wmqjava/MQSample.java, jmscc.samples, k700, k700-L080529 1.4.1.1 08/06/01 09:37:53";

    // define the name of the QueueManager
     private static final String qManager = "MY_Q_MGR";

  // and define the name of the Queue
  private static final String qName = "SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE";

  /**
   * Main entry point
   * 
   * @param args - command line arguments (ignored)
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "MY IP ADDRESS";
        MQEnvironment.channel = "MY_QM_CHANNEL";
        MQEnvironment.port = 5030;


      // Create a connection to the QueueManager
      System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager: " + qManager);
      System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager is finished: " + qManager);
      // Set up the options on the queue we wish to open
      int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;

      // Now specify the queue that we wish to open and the open options
      System.out.println("Accessing queue: " + qName);
      MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager); // here i got error
      System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager is finished: " + qManager);
      // Set up the options on the queue we wish to open
      int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;

      // Now specify the queue that we wish to open and the open options
      System.out.println("Accessing queue: " + qName);
      MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a Sever connection (`SVRCONN`) type channel, not `SDR` type. A `SVRCONN`type channel is required for clients applications to connect to queue manager where `SDR` type channel is for communication between two queue managers.

When a queue manager is created, a default SVRCONN channel, `SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN` is created. You can use this for your tests. But in production it's recommended to create your own channel and not use any predefined channels.

Please see this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqtac.doc/wq11160_.htm) for complete details what you need to do. This is from WebSphere MQ Quick Beginnings book.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have just made the program run.